# Unexpected result after using generator expression

Tags: python

I am trying to filter some data I am working with to take out some artifacts such as negative numbers and errors in my measuring devices.  I have been playing with the idea of using a generator to do this.  I am using Python 2.7.2

```
testlist = [12,2,1,1,1,0,-3,-3,-1]  

gen = (i for i, x in enumerate(testlist) if x < 0 or x > 2.5)

for i in gen: testlist.pop(i)

print testlist
```

This returns:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, -3]
```

My question is why is the -3 value showing up in the updated "testlist"?

Comment: Just curious: why use a generator rather than a list comprehension? Is the real list you're using this on particularly large?

Comment: The actual list is several thousand values, so I don't think it is particularly large.  As far as generator vs. list comprehension, the only reason I started with the less efficient method is due to inexperience.

Comment: Some light background reading on the difference ;) Have fun: http://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/456188

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you remove items from your list, the indexes of the items after it change (they are all shifted down by one). As a result, the generator will skip over some items. Try adding some more print statements so that you can see what is going on:

```
for i in gen:
        print i
        print testlist
        testlist.pop(i)
```

Output:

```
0
[12, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, -3, -3, -1]
5
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, -3, -3, -1]
6
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, -3, -1]
```

You would have needed to delete items at index 0, 5, 5, 5. The generator produces the indexes 0, 5, 6. That makes sense because `enumerate` returns `0, 1, 2, ...` etc. It won't return the same index twice in a row.

It's also very inefficient to remove the elements one at a time. This requires moving data around multiple times, with a worst case performance of O(n<sup>2</sup>). You can instead use a list comprehension.

```
testlist = [x for x in testlist if 0 <= x <= 2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list you are working on, somewhat analogous to modifying the index value of, for instance, a for-loop from *inside* the loop, in some other languages. Consider this approach as an alternative:

```
testlist = [x for x in testlist if x >= 0 and x <= 2.5]
```

using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) should work more directly, though it's not a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), but could trivially changed to one:

```
testlist = (x for x in testlist if x >= 0 and x <= 2.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a simpler input:

```
[-3, -4, -5]
```

First (0, -3) is taken from the enumerator. 0 is added to the generator. The for loop notices that a new element is available from the generator and removes -3:

```
[-4, -5]
```

Take a new element from the enumerator. The enumerator remembers taking the first element, so it will now take the second: -5. -5 is removed from the list in the same way. -4 remains.

By the way, an easier way to do what you're trying is the following:

```
testlist = filter(lambda x: x >= 0 and x <= 2.5, testlist)
```

Comment: The pop that is supposed to remove the first -3 does remove the first one, but then the second one is skipped. This can be seen by changing one of the -3s to a -4.

Comment: Nice use of filter - your lambda could simplify to `lambda x: 0 <= x <= 2.5`

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, I didn't know Python accepts that style of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is to use a list comprehension to create a new filtered list:

```
testlist = [12,2,1,1,1,0,-3,-3,-1]  

testlist[:] = [x for x in testlist if 0 <= x <= 2.5]
```

giving:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: +1  I like your idea of assigning to `testlist[:]` to avoid changing the reference.

Comment: I got it from Alex Martelli, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python.